# Regex matching an optional part of a document?

Tags: python, regex

I have a plain text document that contains varies freeform records that look like one of these two:

```
Title: Red car
Date: 2021-02-10
    
Description: This car is very red.
It goes very fast.

There are many like it but this one is mine.
```

Second:

```
Title: Blue truck
Date: 2021-02-11
    
Description: The truck is blue.
It carries a lot of stuff.

Notes: This one looks damaged.
```

I'm trying to use a regex in Python3 with named groups to capture the fields. The "Notes" field in optional. The closest I've gotten is:

```
(?:Description:)(?P<description>.+?)\n\n(?:Notes:)?(?P<notes>.+)?
```

But it's still capturing text into "notes" even when the word "Notes:" doesn't appear in the document. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're making the word "Notes" optional and the text after it optional, separately. Meaning that either of them can appear on its own. You need to make them both optional as one unit. Use a non-capturing group for that: `(?:Notes:(?P<notes>.+))?`

Answer (score 2):

Because of the regex is greedy, so you need exclude `Notes:` first, then match next Notes. And the `?` operator should only specify once.

Here's my regex expression:

```
(?:^Description: (?P<description>(?:(?!^Notes: ).)+))(?:^Notes: (?P<note>.+))?
```

Please test here:

https://regex101.com/r/CgK1VH/1

But, to be honest, I don't suggest you to do it by regex, especially the text file is too large. The matcher will be very slow.

Just use `file.readlines` and use `line.startswith` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could first match description followed by all lines that do not start with Notes or Title. Then optionally match the line with notes.

```
Description:(?P<description>.+(?:\r?\n(?!(?:Notes|Title):).*)*)(?:\s*\r?\n(?P<notes>Notes:.*))?
```

The pattern matches:

- `Description:` Match literally
- `(?P<description>` Named group `description`

  - `.+(?:\r?\n(?!(?:Notes|Title):).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with Notes: and Title:
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s*\r?\n` Match optional whitespace chars and a newline
  - `(?P<notes>Notes:.*)` Named group `notes`, match the whole line
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LLElai/1)